# How to fix ENOTFOUND error when running Mineflayer Minecraft bot in Python?

Tags: javascript, python, bots, minecraft

Minecraft bot mineflayer not working python

```
` from javascript import require, Once, once

mineflayer = require("mineflayer")

random_number = id([]) % 1000  
BOT_USERNAME = f'colab_{random_number}'

bot = mineflayer.createBot({
    'host': 'true host',  
    'port': "true port",  
    'username': 'ggBot',
    'hideErrors': False
})

# autorizstion
once(bot, 'login')
bot.chat('I spawned')`
```

but error:

```
Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND timamozg.aternos.me:44286
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (node:dns:107:26) {
  errno: -3008,
  code: 'ENOTFOUND',
  syscall: 'getaddrinfo',
  hostname: 'tima.aternos.me:44286'
}

Process finished with exit code 0
```

port and host are correct

in general, this library was originally made for javascript, but it can also be used in python using javascript import

Comment: Did you enter the full host:port in the place where you were just supposed to put the host?

Answer (score 0):

i think it is because of your username make it simple like "MinecraftBot", I Hope It helps!

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34802650)